# Execute Python script from Android app in Java?

Tags: java, android, python, scripting

I am trying to find a way to execute a Python script from my Java code in Android. I did a research on this matter but the only thing I found is, how I can convert python scripts in APK for android (Kivy e.t.c.).

More specifically I have a script which contains a lot of functions.What i want to do is to create an object based on this python script inside my java code and via this object to call my functions.

I can't convert my Python code into Java, because I use various libraries that exists only in python.

Any advice would be helpful and deeply appreciated.

---

The following a snippet of my Python script. I use the library charm for cryptography.

```py
from charm.core.math.integer import integer,serialize,deserialize
class serializeClass:
    def __init__(self)
        ...

    def serialize(self, charm_object):
        assert type(charm_object) == integer, "required type is integer, not: ", type(charm_object)
        return serialize(charm_object)

    def deserialize(self, object):
        assert type(object) == bytes, "required type is bytes, not: ", type(object)
    return deserialize(object)
```

Comment: Could you provide some snippets of the python code.

Comment: Maybe use [jython](http://www.jython.org/).

Comment: I added a simple sample of my script.I want to find a way to call these funcs from my java code

Comment: @PL13 : Were you able to figure out a way to call a python object inside Java ?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a Web Service API to allow your python results be served up over HTTP. Then it's just a matter of Android communicating with an HTTP web service which is simple.

You might find some python to java bridge out there but in my experience these things always have limitations in practice and seem great in theory but don't end up working correctly.

Comment: Yup i have thought of these option but my app will be a part of proxy re-encryption project so i have to run python on an android device in order to re-encrypt my data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SL4A project which would allow you run your Python code on Android.

- Github: https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a
- Tutorials: https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a/blob/wiki/Tutorials.md

Answer (score 0):

Check out Qpython, could be an easy solution. You can run your python script against the Qpython android python core, or deploy yours.

Checkout this repository: https://github.com/qpython-android/app-call-qpython-api