# How to use a python program in libgdx?

Tags: python, libgdx

Say I have a libgdx tic tac toe game and I want to make an AI in python to play against the user. Is there any way to run the AI from a java class ? If yes will it work for android ? Thanks for spending your time.

Answer (score 0):

For executing Python code from Java, please see [Calling Python in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java)

For executing Python from an Android project written in Java, please check [Execute python script from android App in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235763/execute-python-script-from-android-app-in-java)

Dependent on how complex your (already written?) AI is, it is maybe easier to port it to java.

Comment: I am trying to import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter. I can do it in a normal java project but it doesnt work in a libgdx project for some reason. The intellisense works but when I run it, it does not compile. I am using intellij